# How to dynamically create multiple charts on one User Control

Tags: plot, graph, charts

I created a user control and have a graph drawn on it. The problem is I need multiple channels to be in sync. I am currently adding the control and adding the plot to each control. But I need 9 channels, and I'd like to be able to have the user determine how many channels using one control.

I thought I could just make it an array like below but it keeps crashing:

```
readonly PlotArea[] LineGraphArea = new  PlotArea[2];

this.LineGraphArea[0].Width = this.WrapperPlot.Width - 100;
this.LineGraphArea[0].Height = this.WrapperPlot.Height - 2;
this.LineGraphArea[0].Top = this.WrapperPlot.Top + 2;
this.LineGraphArea[0].Left = this.WrapperPlot.Left + 6;
this.LineGraphArea[0].BackColor = BackgroundColor;
this.Controls.Add(this.LineGraphArea[0]);
```

I know I could just do this:

```
readonly PlotArea LineGraphArea1 = new  PlotArea();
readonly PlotArea LineGraphArea2 = new  PlotArea();
readonly PlotArea LineGraphArea3 = new  PlotArea();
```

But I'm sure there's got to be an easier more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: No responses . . . I'm guessing this can't be done.